# SQL Server 2000 Job calls procedure and fails: Must Declare Variable @intVariableName

Tags: t-sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2000

All,

I have a job set up that runs nightly, and, every couple months it will fail when executing a stored procedure on the database. Then, the next night, it runs fine. It's always the same error message:

"Must declare the variable '@intAccountIdent'. [SQLSTATE 01000] (Message 18014)."

I can ensure you that this variable is declared at the top of my procedure, along with many others.

This job has been around for years now, and only recently has it started popping up with this error. I have profiled it, tore it apart, verified that the version in SVN is the same as what's on the server... nothing has changed, yet, this keeps occurring. I've dug around on the web and haven't been able to find anything that could give me any sort of help on this.

Has anyone run into a similar situation? To be honest, I don't know if I'm looking for a solution or more so an explanation of how an error like this can just magically resolve itself and go away?

Any insight is greatly appreciated!

Thanks.

Comment: post the code for your procedure

Comment: the procedure is 2000+ lines, and, seeing as I've never posted on here before, I don't really know what the etiquette is for posting large amounts of code. :\

Answer (score 0):

I'd try to have SQL Profiler running when the error happens, tracking events SP:StmtStarted, SP:StmtCompleted, and Exceptions (and possibly also those events that track queries being submitted by the application to the database). This may show oddness going on when the procedure runs.

This will probably also produce tens of thousands of rows of data to sift through, so filtering it down to as few rows as possible will be important. (Filtering on ObjectName = your procedure name is a start.)

Can you get it to reliably fail, or is it essentially random? Comparing good runs vs. bad runs may also be useful.